# Why does IOHandler.ReadStream blocks thread when client connects to server in Indy?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, indy, indy10

Today I faced a weird behavior using Indy 10 (shipped with Delphi 2010). Here is the problem:

Suppose we have a IdTcpClient in our client, and a IdTcpServer in our server app, and this code in OnExecute event-handler for our IdTcpServer:

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  AStream: TStringStream;
  S: string;
begin
  AStream := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(AStream);
    S := AStream.DataString;
  finally
    AStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Now, when the client tries to connect to the server, using TIdTcpClient.Connect; on the server, TIdTcpServer.OnExecute is invoked, and the thread running inside OnExecute event-handler is blocked when execution reaches AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(AStream) line!

When I trace the code, the problem is caused when ReadLongInt is called inside ReadStream to get bytes count. ReadLongInt calls ReadBytes. Inside ReadBytes, FInputBuffer.Size is zero. There, in a loop ReadFromSource is called, and eventually execution reaches to TIdSocketListWindows.FDSelect which calls "select" function from WinSock2, and execution stops here, and nothing will be received from that client connection. I tried giving value to AByteCount and AReadUntilDisconnect parameters too, but it did not change the behavior.

If I replace ReadStream with ReadLn, then connecting to server does not block code execution, and the data sent from client is read by server.

Is there anything wrong with the code? Or is this a bug?

Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in your code, not in `ReadStream()`. It is acting as designed.

It accepts 3 parameters for input:

```
procedure ReadStream(AStream: TStream; AByteCount: TIdStreamSize = -1; AReadUntilDisconnect: Boolean = False); virtual;
```

You are only providing a value for the first parameter, so the other two parameters use default values.

When the `AByteCount` parameter is set to -1 and the `AReadUntilDisconnect` parameter is set to False, `ReadStream()` is designed to assume that the first 4 bytes received (or 8 bytes, if the `IOHandler.LargeStream` property is set to True) are the length of the data being sent, followed by the actual data afterwards.  That is why `ReadStream()` is calling `ReadLongInt()`.  Not only does this tell `ReadStream()` when to stop reading, but it also allows `ReadStream()` to pre-size the target TStream for better memory management before receiving the data.

If the client is not actually sending a 4-byte (or 8-byte) length value ahead of its data, then `ReadStream()` will still interpret the beginning bytes of the real data as a length.  This typically (but not always, depending on the data) results in `ReadLongInt()` (or `ReadInt64()`) returning a large integer value, which would then cause `ReadStream()` to expect a huge amount of data that will never actually arrive, thus blocking the reading indefinately (or until a timeout occurs, if the `IOHandler.ReadTimeout` property is set to a non-infinite timeout).

In order to use `ReadStream()` effectively, it needs to know when to stop reading, either by being told how much data to expect ahead of time (ie: `AByteCount >= 0`), or by requiring the sender to disconnect after sending its data (ie: `AReadUtilDisconnect = True`).  The combination of `AByteCount = -1` and `AReadUtilDisconnect = False` is a special case, when the length is encoded directly in the streaming.  This is primarily used (but not limited to) when the sender calls `IOHandler.Write(TStream)` with its `AWriteByteCount` parameter set to True (it is False by default).

When dealing with non-textual data, it is always a good idea to send the data length ahead of the actual data whenever possible.  It optimizes reading operations.

The different parameter combinations of ReadStream() work out to the following logic:

1. AByteCount = -1, AReadUtilDisconnect = False: read 4/8 bytes, interpret as a length, then keep reading until that length is received.
2. AByteCount < -1, AReadUtilDisconnect = False: assume AReadUntilDisconnect is True and keep reading until disconnected.
3. AByteCount > -1, AReadUtilDisconnect = False: pre-size the target TStream and keep reading until AByteCount number of bytes are received.
4. AByteCount <= -1, AReadUtilDisconnect = True: keep reading until disconnected.
5. AByteCount > -1, AReadUtilDisconnect = True: pre-size the target TStream and keep reading until disconnected.

Depending on the kind of data the client is actually sending to the server in the first place, chances are that `ReadStream()` is likely not the best choice for reading that data.  The IOHandler has many different kinds of reading methods available.  For instance, if the client is sending delimited text (especially if it is being sent with `IOHandler.WriteLn()`), then `ReadLn()` is a better choice.

Comment: Thank you for your through description. It is mentioned in Indy documentation that if AByteCount is -1 and AReadUntilDisconnect is False, byte count is read as an integer from IOHandler, but I didn't know it would be read from the first 4 or 8 bytes of the received data. I thought when AReadUntilDisconnect is False and AByteCount is -1, ReadStream would read as long as there is something in input buffer. Anyways, thanks again for your help.

Comment: All of the IOHandler's reading methods get their data from the InputBuffer only.  The ReadBytes() method, which the other methods call internally, makes sure that the InputBuffer has enough bytes available in it for each read operation.  If the InputBuffer already has 4 bytes in it, then ReadStream() receives them as-is.  If the InputBuffer does not have 4 bytes yet, ReadBytes() makes sure it does, then ReadStream() receives them from the InputBuffer afterwards.  Either way, all data goes from the socket into the InputBuffer to each reading method as needed.